# Why is the second execution of this combinator 10 times faster than the first?

Tags: f#

I am working on a parser combinator library and found some behavior I couldn't explain.  The first time I run the combinator it runs significantly slower than the second time that I run it.  I repo'd the behavior with this small app (running Release with optimizations on)

```
let (>>=) first callback state = 
    let reply = first state
    callback reply state

let time f = 
    let start = System.DateTime.Now
    f()
    printfn "%s" ((System.DateTime.Now - start).ToString())

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 

    let x1 state = "foo"

    let compound = 
        x1 >>= fun i ->
        x1 >>= fun j ->
        x1 >>= fun a ->
        x1 >>= fun b ->
        x1 >>= fun c ->
        x1 >>= fun d ->
        x1 >>= fun e ->
        x1 >>= fun f ->
        x1 >>= fun j ->                
               fun _ -> [i;j;a;b;c;d;e;f]


    time (fun () -> compound "a" |> ignore)
    time (fun () -> compound "b" |> ignore)
    time (fun () -> compound "c" |> ignore)


    0
```

Running this output I get

```
00:00:00.0090009
00:00:00.0010001
00:00:00
```

Why is the first iteration so much slower than the second or third?

---

Edit, so I tried this out in C# as well.  It runs faster, but the results are similar.

```
using System;

namespace fssharp
{
    public delegate string Parser(string state);

    public delegate Parser Callback(string result);

    public class Combinator
    {
        public static Parser Combine(Parser p, Callback callback)
        {
            Parser r = state =>
            {
                var result = p(state);
                return callback(result)(state);
            };

            return r;
        }

        public static string X1(string state)
        {
            return "foo";
        } 
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parser comb = state => 
                                Combinator.Combine(Combinator.X1, result  =>
                                Combinator.Combine(Combinator.X1, result2 =>
                                Combinator.Combine(Combinator.X1, result3 =>
                                Combinator.Combine(Combinator.X1, result4 =>
                                Combinator.Combine(Combinator.X1, result5 =>
                                Combinator.Combine(Combinator.X1, result6 =>
                                Combinator.Combine(Combinator.X1, result7 =>
                                Combinator.Combine(Combinator.X1, result8 =>
                                Combinator.Combine(Combinator.X1, result9 => s => result + result2 + result3 +result4 +result5 +result6 +result7+result8+result9)))
                                ))))))(state);

            var now = DateTime.Now;

            comb("foo");

            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - now);

            now = DateTime.Now;

            comb("foo2");

            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - now);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints out

```
00:00:00.0030003
00:00:00
```

I'm now curious why C# is faster here

Comment: Is it faster the first time or the second? You state both in the original question.

Comment: My apologies, the first is slower. I will update the question

Comment: Probably something to do with the compiler pre-loading bytecode?  Does the third time run the same as the second?

Comment: @mydogisbox, yeah, all subsequent times run as fast as the second time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even tough I can't tell for sure, it is either:

1. JIT: The function is JIT'ed the first time it runs, and then it uses the already compiled version
2. It detects that the same function is called with the same parameters and cache the result.

Try to call it with a different parameter. If the time stays the same it's 2, if time is different it's 1

Comment: Updated the sample to use different input arguments. Sounds like its A. Is there any way to force a JIT beforehand to validate the hypothesis?

Comment: There is no way to do that to my knowledge.  It has to do with how the VM loads bytecode.

Comment: Fiddle with ngen (http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @VincentHubert I've tried ngen installing the app and it didn't make a difference.  I got the same result

Comment: Beyond curiosity, why do you care if this is slower the first time because of JIT overhead?  Also, are you sure that ngen actually worked?  Finally, ngen may actually make performance worse (both start-up and general performance).

Comment: Also, could be hardware related. If the code runs fast enough, maybe it stays in the CPU cache long enough to be present when running the second time. If you sleep() for a minute between calls, do you have the same result?

Comment: @Mr.Putty, well, in my parser combinator library the use case is to run the parser once. I only noticed the difference while testing the combinator in a loop looking for performance issues. In production,  with a larger combinator, the performance hit is enormous. For example, parsing 25MB took 600ms the first time, but 25ms the second time.  I'd rather have it be 25ms every time!  Also, I am not sure that ngen actually worked, is there a way to validate that?  I only wanted to ngen to validate vincent's answer

Comment: That's odd. Are you saying that the first-time run-time is impacted by the volume of data to be parsed? I would expect the JIT overhead to be insensitive to the input. Maybe I'm misunderstanding. Anyway, if you want to tell that ngen worked, the first step is to look for mscorjit.dll being loaded by your process. If it is, your ngen probably didn't take. Lots of details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163610.aspx (see Final Notes). However, that article's a bit short on the drawbacks. See this for a different perspective: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163610.aspx

Comment: @Mr.Putty, just saying that in a production combinator there are lots of delayed closures, so if the JIT has to deal with a TON of F# closures, then the timing can be significant. My example in the original question is contrived to demonstrate the issue.  Anyways, thanks for the links, I'll take a look at it.